# How to return render_template in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, rendering, owlready

The following code works perfectly from the .py file but I want to separate the HTML and put it in templates/index.html.

I suppose I have to use the render_template function in Flask to be able to return the same results.

```
# File dynamic_website.py
from owlready2 import *
onto = get_ontology("bacteria.owl").load()
 
from flask import Flask, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
 
@app.route('/')
def ontology_page():
    html  = """<html><body>"""
    html += """<h2>'%s' ontology</h2>""" % onto.base_iri
    html += """<h3>Root classes</h3>"""
    for Class in Thing.subclasses():
        html += """<p><a href="%s">%s</a></p>""" % (url_for("class_page", iri = Class.iri), Class.name)
      
    html += """</body></html>"""
    return html
```

I created a folder template and a file index.html. I used return render_template('index.html') but it doesn't work. What arguments do I have to add to the return_template function? "for Class in Thing.subclasses():" have to be in the .html file or .py file? What about the url_for function?

If you could edit the .py code and let me know what should I write exactly in the index.html file to have the same results it would be great.

UPDATE:

What I have done:

[Python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCwFr.png)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from owlready2 import *
from flask import Flask, url_for

onto = get_ontology("bacteria.owl").load()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")


def ontology_page():
    for Class in Thing.subclasses():

        return render_template('index.html')
```

[Html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXRTf.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ Class.name }}</h1>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"but it doesn't work."* Please give a proper error description including the full traceback.

Comment: `I created a folder templates and a file index.html. I used return render_template('index.html') but it doesn't work.` Without sharing the actual code that doesn't work - ie the content of the template and the code you're using to render it - it's very difficult for anyone to point out what you're doing wrong!

Comment: @KlausD. from flask import Flask, render_template
from owlready2 import *
from flask import Flask, url_for

onto = get_ontology("app.owl").load()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")


def ontology_page():
    for Class in Thing.subclasses():
    
        return render_template('index.html')


Is this the correct py code?

Comment: @RobinZigmond - I put 2 pictures on my post with the code.

Comment: Please add all information to the question itself as text, no screenshots of code.

Comment: @KlausD.  - now you can find the information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return a function multiple times. Whatever is returned, is the value of the function. [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Dg9sR4i4Qk) is in JS, but it implies the same concept as python does.

If you want the user to see a list of things on the html, do this. `render_template('index.html', things=Thing.Subclasses())` This will give Jinja a list, where it can then for loop.

For html you can do this
`{% for s in things %} {{ s }} is something {% endfor %}`. Do anything you want with the `s` though, `s` is one subclass from the list.

Comment: Thanks Ajitesh - It partially work, it returns the class names. I need also to return the page IRI and every class to be a link also. In the initial code (.py file) it was "        html += """<p><a href="%s">%s</a></p>""" % (url_for("class_page", iri = Class.iri), Class.name)". How do I add this also? What about url_for function? I still need to use it?

Comment: You should put the url_for function inside your index.html. Maybe write something like `<a href="{{ url_for("class_page", iri = Class.iri) }}">{{ Class.name }}</a>` in your index.html.
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/templates/